# How to create collage video with still and moving photos?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, cs5, video

I'm looking to create a collage of images that include both still and video - similar to this
[video collage](https://www.instagram.com/p/BV2PrGeAnh7/?taken-by=parkncube) using Photoshop CS5. Basically, I have 3 landscape photos and one video that I want to stylistically position onto one page, and export as a short loop for Instagram. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it can be done with just CS5 -- I went from CS3 to CC.

From what I see online you need CS5 Extended.

So with CS5 Extended it should be fairly straight forward. Create a document to the size for Instagram, position your static images, and your video, and export as an .mp4.

Without CS5 Extended its likely more complicated:

Might be able to get it as a .GIF but will need to use a 3rd party [utility app](https://www.google.com/search?q=GIF%20to%20MP4&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) to convert .GIF to .mp4 if you want to use it on Instagram.

As for the actual creation the only way you'll be able to do it in Photoshop CS5 is to frame by frame it. You can either find a utility app to convert whatever your video file currently is to individual frames; or since you only plan to use it on Instagram you could do it by taking screenshots every few frames in a [video player capable of scrubbing](https://superuser.com/questions/45803/video-players-that-have-frame-by-frame-playback-feature).

---

If you're wondering the loop part, you'll just want to double the frames after a point going in essentially reverse back to the starting point.

---

All of this would be a lot easier with a video editor such as After Effects or Premier. If you don't have either there are free alternatives:

- [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve)
- [OpenShot](http://www.openshot.org/)
- [Avid Media Composer](http://www.avid.com/media-composer-first)